# SSL Certifcate not Working 80% of the time Apache

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am having a problem with `HTTPS` on my domain. `fashiontex.co`

Across all browsers on (Linux Desktop), it sometimes loads as `https` without the Not Secured Warning or

> "Your connection is not private"

on chrome and its other variation on different browsers.

On, mobile IOS 14, Android, and others it is 100% not secured no matter the configuration.

For the records, I am using `PossitiveSSL certificate` which isn't free.

here is a snippet of the relevant `ssl` and `virtual host` config

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.co
    ServerAlias www.example.co
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.co/public_html
    ....
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:+HIGH:!ADH:!EXP:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!NULL:!aNULL
   SSLHonorCipherOrder on

   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
   SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/fashiontex.ca-bundle
</VirtaulHost>
```

For the SSLCipherSuite, I'm not going to exaggerate, I have used over 50 values searching the internet.

and on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=fashiontex.co I have gotten ratings of A, B but still, it still doesn't work even after clearing the cache on both windows, iPhone, and ubuntu.

PS: Before writing this entire post, it was showing not secured, when I was done with the above, I refreshed and it showed without the warning and tried again 10 seconds later and it is the same problem of not secured one more time. Please what am I missing?

Comment: looks like there is some DDoS protection emabled which intercepts the traffic and causes a self-signed certificate. See https://github.com/MichaIng/DietPi/issues/3853 for similar issues.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I ran the command and my did't show a self signed certificate as return value openssl s_client -showcerts -connect - domain.co:443

Comment: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect fashiontex.co:443` gives me a certificate issued for `CN = DDoS-Filter.domain` and issued by `CN=protect@DDoS-Filter.domain` - i.e. by some private CA. This is exactly like described in the github issue I've linked to.

Comment: I have it working now as you were correct. Layer 7 SSL Protection was disabled by my hosting and every works like magic now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was truly the Layer 7 SSL Protection which was enabled that was interfering with requests because it intercepts https requests for DDoS protection.

Depending on your hosting provider, mine recommended switching protection to Sensor Mode unless I am been attacked frequently.

So now it works